# OLAP Query Cube Issues to config connection string for not login many times?

Tags: excel, powerbi, connection-string, cube, olap-cube

Can someone have solutions for this:

1. I exported data from Power BI Service via '**Analyze in Excel**' feature.
   [image]
2. When open downloaded Excel file, i have a pivot table can be refreshed. But the issue i have met which whenever i do refresh the pivot, a Login (like image) pop up, then i have to click on the account to process next. And i have tried many way to config connection string **for not login when refresh connection**, but it doesn't work.
   [image]

Original connection string (changed private value to xxxx)

```
Provider=MSOLAP.8;Integrated Security=ClaimsToken;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=sobe_wowvirtualserver-4e0a2dc1-a733-4709-aeec-xxxxxxxx;Data Source=pbiazure://api.powerbi.com;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Identity Provider=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common, https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api, 929d0ec0-7a41-4b1e-bc7c-xxxxxxx;Update Isolation Level=2
```

Tried connection string but it doesn't work, return this notification image
[image]

```
Provider=MSOLAP;Password=123456;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ex@company.com;Initial Catalog=sobe_wowvirtualserver-4e0a2dc1-a733-4709-aeec-3f07b7cdb3ee;Data Source=pbiazure://api.powerbi.com;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Identity Provider=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common, https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api, 929d0ec0-7a41-4b1e-bc7c-b754a28bddcc;Update Isolation Level=2
```

Thank you for your helps.